# What is the best way to validate input parameters?

Tags: rest

I'm creating a simple Rest Api with the basic layering Controller-Service-Repository.

I have the following questions:

1. Where should I check if the correct parameters are given?
2. How should I validate thiese parameters e.g throw Response error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could validate your parameters on the first middleware (or after the authorization middleware). For example, in an express application you could pass your request body into a `joi` validation scheme.
2. Depends on your business logic. You can either set default values for parameters not defined by user or throw error. For example, if a user has not given any `username` or `password` parameter, then you should throw an error. All errors should be handled by the last middleware and return a relevant status code (401, 402, etc) with an information message if needed.